# Why is GPOTool not finding all my GPOs?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have 91 group policy objects linked to my domain. When I run `GPOTool.exe` it only finds and reports on 47. Why would the results be missing the rest?

I am running Windows 2008 R2 on all 6 domain controllers.

Comment: Have you tried just using Group Policy Management Console?

Comment: Yes, all 91 GPOs show find in the management console. I am using GPOTool to find some errors between servers.

Comment: You can use some other tools to find the errors between servers as well.  Did you know that?  DCDIAG, REPLMON, REPADMIN just to name a few.

Comment: Yes, I have been using DCDIAG and REPADMIN as well. I am having issues with SYSVOL replication and permission. AD all checks out fine.

My specific question was about GPOTool only finding some of the policies though, any thoughts on why that would be?

Comment: The first thought that pops into my head if you're having replication issues is that GPOTool is accessing another DC that isn't fully replicated from the others yet... not sure though as I'd need to inspect more to find out for sure.  Do you have AD SYSVOL version mismatches on your GPOs?